# maven compiler plugin 2.0.2

Tags: java, maven

Can you please tell me is it mandatory to specify the maven-compiler-plugin details in my POM under:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
```

If yes why so, i understand what it does, but not sure why its required? Isnt there any other way to invoke the javac in maven?

Comment: Question title indicates `2.0.2` - is this a version you want to use or that gets used?  Which version of maven are you in?

Comment: maven version is 2.1.0, its the compiler plugin in the title

Comment: The answers are below. You should look at using a newer version of maven with support for newer version of compiler plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Can you please tell me is it mandatory to specify the maven-compiler-plugin details?*

No. But it will use Java 1.3 or something from stone age to compile.

*If yes why so, i understand what it does, but not sure why its required?*

The answer is 'No'. But here is the reason. You sure do not want to compile using Java 1.3 on your new code. You want all the new features in Java 5. Don't you? :) So, you have to add these extra lines in your already cluttered POM.

*Isnt there any other way to invoke the javac in maven?*

There isn't. But `mvn compile` or any other command will work even if you do not have this block. But compilation will fail if your source code has any advance stuffs that is in Java 5, but not in previous version.

---

**Edit 1**

How does it compile to 1.3 when I have JDK 5?

Well, there is an option to set to do so in Java compiler. See Java compiler options here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

It says you can set `source` et al to older version.

Comment: maven `3.0.4` uses `1.5` as source version, if compiler plugin is not explicitly defined.

Comment: @Raghuram yeah, I guess this was a long pending and highly desired request in Maven community. Sadly, they gave this feature by default when Java 6 is counting days. :) people want Java 6 on newer projects now. :)

Comment: Yup you are spot on, the code was compiling with JDK 1.3 even though i have my JAVA_HOME pointing to 1.6. But not sure why it does that?

Comment: @hakish updated. Why does it do that. because Maven sets `-source` options to `1.3` by default.

Answer (score 4):

The [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) section is optional. Defaults are applied if you don't include that section in your pom.xml.

> The default compiler is javac and is used to compile Java sources.
>   Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the
>   default target setting is 1.5, independently of the JDK you run Maven
>   with.

My personal preference is to have an explicit configuration for the reasons below.

1. I do not think relying on external defaults is a good idea as
   these *may* change when the version of the plugin is changed.
2. It is unlikely that I would want a *new* project to be compiled for
   Java 1.5

Comment: Mine is compiling with version 1.3 by default.