# Why maven is using maven-compiler-plugin 2.0.2 instead 3.0?

Tags: maven

I tried to build some maven project. It failed becasue maven used older java 1.3, and project is using generics. I knwo that I can overwrite maven-compiler-plugin version and source and target, but that's not the point.

Steps to reproduce

```
$ git clone https://github.com/DuLerWeil/netty-diameter && cd netty-diameter
$ mvn help:effective-pom
...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

My settings:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_72, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-28-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
$ printenv JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
$ readlink -f $(type -p java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

Comment: Based on the [default bindings](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html) you should be using version 2.3.2 which has a default of [1.5](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-80). Something must be overwriting this. This page details how maven resolves plugins (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-resolution.html), while the following details how it resolves plugins based on prefixes (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) Might help you pinpoint where the wrong plugin is being defined.

Comment: The basic problem is that in the project no definition of the maven-compiler-plugin exists which means Maven will pickup the one which you have in your local repository. This results from an earlier run with Maven 2.2.1 or with a project which defined the maven-compiler-plugin version to 2.0.2. This is an indicator that the given project is not correctly configured to work with Maven (no definitions of the plugins for example).

Comment: One solution can also be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557874/maven-compiler-plugin-2-0-2

Answer (score 0):

your JAVA_HOME needs to point to a JDK not a JRE. JDK is the Java Development Environment, only this one contains the javac executable (the compiler). The maven compiler plugin uses the javac compiler - it is not a compiler itself.

The compiler plugin has some configuration to define the java version too. See "source" and "target" in
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

a usage example can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html - you can probably delete the execution configuration - since it looks like the defaults.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. From the question "_I know that I can overwrite maven-compiler-plugin version and source and target, but that's not the point._". rofrol wants to know why maven is using version 2.0.2 of the compiler plugin and not version 3.0.

Comment: I think that is mixed up, no version 3.0 is shown, the pom contains <version>2.0.2</version> so that ok. the only 3.x version I see are maven itself and the linux kernel.

Comment: The **effective-pom** is showing version 2.0.2. So this is what maven is using. If I understand the question properly rofrol is not explicitly setting this in his pom. He would like to know where this configuration is coming from.

Comment: That's right. maven is using old maven-compiler-plugin effectively setting source to java 1.3

Comment: well search the project for "maven-compiler-plugin" - someone overwrites your version. It may be just a typo in the configuration you use - so it is ignored. Another option would be to check the settings.xml files (mvn help:effective-settings) may in there is a profile that defines this version.

Comment: maven used maven-compiler-plugin that was already in .m2. It was old version installed by some other package.